# Azure self-hosted agent in background

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps and was hoping somebody would be able to help me out.

I've installed and set-up a self-hosted agent that works successfully when running the run.cmd. However, the moment I close this command window the agent goes offline. Is there a way to run the agent in the background permanently without the command window open?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've read the documentation, it says to look into service.msc. I can see they Azure agent in there, it's listed as running but it says it's offline. The agent only appears as online when I run the run.cmd from within the folder, and goes offline again as soon as I close it

Comment: Figured it out - needed a slight tweak to the proxy settings

Comment: Gladly to hear that you have resolved this issue. We suggest that you post it as the answer so that it can help others who have the same issue in the future. Thank you for helping us build a better StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of solved the solution, there was an issue with the proxy behind a corporate firewall which for some strange reason meant the build agent would only work interactively

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: you need to run runsvc.sh